# Contacts management implementation on Android

Tags: java, android, contacts

I'm planning to implement an app that able to manage user's contacts, basically do things like [the API defined by W3C](http://www.w3.org/2012/sysapps/contacts-manager-api/)

But I'm totally new to Android/Java, not sure where to start.

Is there a library or api that I can use? Or any suggestions?

Comment: Refer this one for contact operations http://androiddevelopement.blogspot.in/2011/07/insert-update-delete-view-contacts-in.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of Android Contacts Provider API for managing user's contacts. Please refer [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html) and also [Contacts Contract](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you provide a simple example, e.g. insert a new contact?